# D3 tooltip not displaying in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, safari, tooltip

I developed a chart some time ago and it was working correctly. Recently I noticed that the tooltip isn't working (anymore) in Firefox although it is working correctly in Safari (both on Mac OS). Can anyone suggest what might cause the problem?

The chart is embedded in a Drupal site at http://www.climateactionnow.ca/cumulative-manmade-emissions-1854-2010

UPDATE: Since posting this I have found a number of reports of errors of this sort using Firefox ... but haven't found a solution yet.

The code is:

```
<script>

var w = 450,
h = 500,
r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
color = d3.scale.category20c();

function prettyAlert(p_message, p_title) {
p_title = p_title || "";
$(p_message).dialog({
   title: p_title,
   width:400,
   height:400,
   resizable: false,
   modal : true,
   overlay: { 
     backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 
     },
   close: function(ev, ui) {
     $(this).remove(); 
     }
});
}
hoverover=d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class","arcs-hoverover")
.style("display","none")
.style("position","absolute");

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.append("svg:g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
.sort(null)
.size([2 * Math.PI, r * r])
.children(function(d) { return isNaN(d.value) ? d3.entries(d.value) : null; })
.value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
.endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
.innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
.outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); })
;

d3.json("../sites/default/d3_files/json/ranking.json", function(json) {

path = svg.data(d3.entries(json)).selectAll("path")
.data(partition.nodes)
.enter().append("svg:path")
.attr("d", arc)
.attr("fill", function(d) { 
     if (d.key != "Not attributed") {
        return color(d.key);
        }
     else {
        return "transparent";
        } // end else
     }) // end fill
 .style("stroke", function(d) { 
     if (d.key == "Not attributed") {
        return "lightgrey";}
     }) // end stroke
.on("click", magnify)
.each(stash)
.on("mouseout",function(d){ 
  d3.select("body")
  .select(".arcs-hoverover")
  .style("display","none");  
  d3.select(this)
  .style("stroke-width","1px")
}) // end mouseout

.on("mousemove",function(d){
   var bodyOffsets = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
   d3.select(this)
     .style("stroke-width","1px");
   d3.select("body")
     .select(".arcs-hoverover")
     .style("display","block") 
     .style("top", (d3.event.clientY - bodyOffsets.top -300)+"px")
     .style("left",(d3.event.clientX - bodyOffsets.left -20)+"px")
     .html(function( ){
          var units=calcUnits(d.key);
           return d.key + "<br />" + d3.round(d.value/1000, 2)+ units;
     }) // end html
  }) // end mousemove

 ; // end append g
}); // end d3.json

function calcUnits (type) {
// str.indexOf("welcome")
if ((type.indexOf("Production")!=-1) || (type.indexOf("Flaring")!=-1))   { // found
  return " GtCO2"
 }
else {
  return " GtCO2e"
 };
};

function clickAlert (label) {
};

// Distort the specified node to 80% of its parent.
function magnify(node) {
if (parent = node.parent) {
var parent,
x = parent.x,
k = .8;
parent.children.forEach(function(sibling) {
    x += reposition(sibling, x, sibling === node
    ? parent.dx * k / node.value
    : parent.dx * (1 - k) / (parent.value - node.value));
});
} else {
reposition(node, 0, node.dx / node.value);
}

path.transition() // was path - undefined
.duration(750)
.attrTween("d", arcTween);
}; // end magnify

// Recursively reposition the node at position x with scale k.
function reposition(node, x, k) {
node.x = x;
if (node.children && (n = node.children.length)) {
    var i = -1, n;
    while (++i < n) x += reposition(node.children[i], x, k);
    }
return node.dx = node.value * k;
}; // end reposition

// Stash the old values for transition.
function stash(d) {
d.x0 = d.x;
d.dx0 = d.dx;
}; // end stash

// Interpolate the arcs in data space.
function arcTween(a) {
var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
return function(t) {
    var b = i(t);
    a.x0 = b.x;
    a.dx0 = b.dx;
    return arc(b);
    };
}; // end arcTween
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in FF when the tooltip `div` comes into display the mouse event `mouseout` gets triggered and so it gets `display:none`.

As a result of which the tooltip is not visible.

So the fix is to make the tooltip div entertain no mouse events.
By using `pointer-events:none` read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

So inside your css add:

```
.arcs-hoverover{
  pointer-events:none
}
```

Or in the code add this after rendering:

```
d3.selectAll(".arcs-hoverover").style("pointer-events", "none");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added  pointer-events to the css and that fixed it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of the tooltip is causing a mouseout event when the cursor is moved. You can alter the distance from the top and left (in your code: -300 and -20) such that the cursor cannot hover over the tooltip.

```
 .style("top", (d3.event.clientY - bodyOffsets.top -300)+"px")
 .style("left",(d3.event.clientX - bodyOffsets.left -20)+"px")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a D3 v4 scatterchart.  My tooltips worked fine in Chrome, Edge, and IE; but not in Firefox. In Firefox tooltips displayed properly for the data points in the lower left side of the chart, but remained hidden and did not display for the data points in the upper right. It was puzzling.

When I followed Cyril Cherian's suggestion to add "pointer-events: none" to the relevant CSS, the problem was resolved in Firefox without breaking in Chrome, Edge, or IE.

```
.tooltip {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
visibility: hidden;
pointer-events: none;    /* <======= added code ====== */
background-color: lightblue;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
```

}

I adopted Cherian's solution when I saw that Chris Williams's example used "pointer-events: none" and it worked in all the browsers I tried.
[D3 scatterchart with tooltips and pointer-events: none](http://bl.ocks.org/williaster/af5b855651ffe29bdca1)